# if exists insert else update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm on an sql2000 (2008 coming soon, yay!) so I can't use the merge statement yet.

I have the insert statment but now need to compose the update statement.  I'd like to wrap this in an if exists insert else update statement.  The query is longer and more complex but if I can get some help with this basic one below, I think I can get the whole thing.

```
insert into systemdetail 
    (systemname, projectname, systemtype)
    select  distinct T.systemname, T.projectname, S.model
        from    sysList T, requestSystems S 
        where   T.systemname = S.systemname and 
            S.systemname not in 
            (
            select d.systemname, d.ProjectName from systemdetail d,syslist t2 where t2.systemname = d.SystemName and t2.projectname=d.ProjectName
            )
```

Written out in English:
If the projectname and systemname exists in the systemdetail table, update it.  Otherwise, insert the projectname and systemname (and other fields) as a new record.

Below is my attempt at writing the if exists but I'm stuck (see ??? within the query).

```
if (exists (select sd.projectname, sd.systemname from systemdetail sd, sysList t where t.projectname = sd.projectname and t.systemname = sd.systemname)
    update systemDetail 
    set projectname = t.projectname, 
    systemname = t.systemname
    where ??? <-- this is where I'm stuck
else
    insert into systemdetail 
    (systemname, projectname, systemtype)
    select  distinct T.systemname, T.projectname, S.model
        from    sysList T, requestSystems S 
        where   T.systemname = S.systemname and 
            S.systemname not in 
            (
            select d.systemname, d.ProjectName from systemdetail d,syslist t2 where t2.systemname = d.SystemName and t2.projectname=d.ProjectName
            )
```

Comment: Why are you doing that update?, you want to update the same values that you first checked were equal on the other table, so you don't need to update anything

Comment: @Lamak The systemDetail is the master table and the requestSystems is a secondary table where a user places a request to have something done to a system.  If the work request is approved, the details provided in the requestSystem will be "moved" to the systemDetail table.  The same system could exists under multiple projectnames.

Comment: Have to agree with @Lamak @jzworkman - are you trying to update `systemtype` if there is already a row matching `systemname` and `projectname`?

Comment: On a separate note: instead of the `IF EXISTS` approach, you could run the `UPDATE` statement first and `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0` then run your `INSERT`

Comment: @diaho Can you show me with code?  The query above is simplified.  I may have shortened the query too much but there are 10 other fields that are to be updated.

Comment: I should also add that this query is being run within a web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
-- Try update first
UPDATE
    S
SET
    systemtype = X.model
FROM
    systemDetail AS S
JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        T.systemname, T.projectname, S.model
    FROM
        sysList T, requestSystems S 
    WHERE
        T.systemname = S.systemname
) AS X
ON
    X.systemname = S.systemname
AND X.projectname = S.projectname

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    insert into systemdetail 
    (systemname, projectname, systemtype)
    select  distinct T.systemname, T.projectname, S.model
        from    sysList T, requestSystems S 
        where   T.systemname = S.systemname and 
            S.systemname not in 
            (
            select d.systemname, d.ProjectName from systemdetail d,syslist t2 where t2.systemname = d.SystemName and t2.projectname=d.ProjectName
            )
END
```

Comment: I'll have to see if I can run this within ColdFusion.  I should note that it worked in my query editor.

Comment: Looks like I CAN run this in ColdFusion!  Excellent!

Comment: When you're doing this sort of operation, it's also a good idea to consider if you could have the data change between the UPDATE and the INSERT. If that is the case, then you should consider increasing the isolation level of the transaction. Without it, one of them could hit a PK violation error if it's the 2nd connection to attempt the INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your update statement is that you are updating both values that you are searching with.  You should be searching for your records using a primary key and updating the other values for the record with that primary key.  You cannot call an update to change the primary key of a record.

Comment: The projectname and systemname together make up the primary key if that helps.